# Is it possible to install only parts of the ffmpeg headers?

Tags: dependencies, docker, ffmpeg

I am trying to use the ffmpeg headers in a dockerized ubuntu environment. If I install all of the ffmpeg header files there it will use up to 900 mbs in image size. This seems not good for my usecase, because I only use it to demux an audio stream from an webm audio container. Such libraries as libswscale-dev or libavfilter-dev shouldn't be required then, right?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could compile it yourself, disable/enable whatever you want, and the resulting header files will be minuscule.